# How do I stop Vim from automatically highlighting the first sentence of my Java comments?

Tags: vim, javadoc

When I write JavaDoc-style comments in my code, Vim highlights the first sentence of them specifically:

[image]

Why does this happen? The problem occurs regardless of the colorscheme I use, so I'm assuming it has something to do with my java.vim file, but I've never modified it or anything.

Comment: This happens because the first sentence of a javadoc comment is special: it is used as the short description in the package, class and method overviews of the index, package and class pages respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like *jackrabbit* said, the first sentence in a Javadoc comment is special. Vim highlights it for you so that you clearly see what will be used as the comment summary in the generated documentation. Still, if it bothers you, you can disable Javadoc highlighting by defining `java_ignore_javadoc` in your vimrc file.

```
let java_ignore_javadoc=1
```

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! I never actually generate JavaDocs though, so thanks for the setting there.